# How to schedule OOZIE job, if any changes happened in given folder?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-streaming, oozie-coordinator, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I want to schedule a oozie job based on folder i.e.

I have a folder in HDFS location and every day one file will be add in that folder with the format of date.txt (exp :20160802.txt ).

I want to schedule a OOZIE batch, if any new file add in that folder.

Please help me on this ,how can I schedule in my use case scenario.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1):

Oozie workflow jobs are run based on regular time intervals and/or data availability. And, in some cases, they can be triggered by an external event. Coordinator comes into play here.

You can use oozie coordinator  to check data dependency and trigger a oozie workflow with Coordinator [EL functions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a3._Expression_Language_for_Parameterization)
In your case every day your file is getting added to hdfs with timestamp.So with dataset you can achieve.

***From Documentation***

**Example** A dataset produced once every day at 00:15 PST8PDT and done-flag is set to empty:

```
  <dataset name="logs" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
           initial-instance="2009-02-15T08:15Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles">
    <uri-template>
      hdfs://foo:9000/app/logs/${market}/${YEAR}${MONTH}/${DAY}/data
    </uri-template>
    <done-flag></done-flag>
  </dataset>
The dataset would resolve to the following URIs and Coordinator looks for the existence of the directory itself:

  [market] will be replaced with user given property.  hdfs://foo:9000/usr/app/[market]/2009/02/15/data
  hdfs://foo:9000/usr/app/[market]/2009/02/16/data
  hdfs://foo:9000/usr/app/[market]/2009/02/17/data
```

Please read the documentation many examples are given there.Its good.

1.[About Coordinators](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a1._Coordinator_Overview)

2.[DataSet](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5._Dataset)